# Remove filename with "-r" in linux

Tags: linux

I am unable to delete a filename named `-r` with `rm -rf -r`
Is there any special trick to remove it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is readily available in the man pages.

Comment: I spam tab until it selects the strangely named file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Linux or Unix-like system you may come across file names with special characters such as:

```
-
--
;
&
$
?
*
White spaces, backslashes and more.
```

> **The problem and solution**

**Tip #1: Try a ./ at the beginning of the filename**

The syntax is as follows to delete a file called '-file':

> $ rm -v ./-file
>
> removed `./-file'

**Tip #2: Try a -- at the beginning of the filename**

```
A -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing     by   shell. 

Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments.
```

> $ rm  -- -file
>
> $ rm  -- --file
>
> $ rm  -- '@#$%^&file'
>
> $ rmdir  -- '--dirnameHere'

Comment: I'd replace the double quotes with single quotes, to avoid having the shell try to interpret things like $ and *.  It's a good habit to get into in general.  I've submitted an edit to that effect.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake: The `--` should of course not be in the beginning of the filename, but previously as a separate argument. The examples are right, of course, only the bolded description is confusing.

Answer (score 12):

As described in the `rm` man pages:

> To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
>   one of these commands:
>
> ```
>       rm -- -foo
>       rm ./-foo
> ```

So, in your case:

```
rm -- -r
```

Or

```
rm ./-r
```